# How to reload a form in a JFrame? I have two forms, form1 and form2:

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How to reload a form in a `JFrame`? I have two forms, form1 and form2:

form1 links to form2 using:

```
new form2().show(); 
this.setVisible(false);
```

form2 links to form1 is success

The problem is when form1 form2 links to existing data are not shown.

I want to ask is there any other way than `setVisible()` method because it seems just to hide it.

Comment: Read about CardLayout. Add both forms (JPanel instances?) to a container with Cardlyout and swap them.

Comment: @DyDy-Zin-Real-UnFake please [learn to accept Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if my answer was useful or comment if it didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You have to `revalidate();` the frame. If that doesn't work you also have to call `repaint();`

JFrame inherits `revalidate()` and `repaint()` methods from [java.awt.Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate%28%29) abstract class